# How to get word vector coordinates in

Tags: python, word2vec

I tried to make word embedding graph and i did it, but I want to get coordinates of each word vector in graph. It means, for example, I want to get each coordinates of showing words

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mubb3.png)

I used python, tensorflow and my code is below one that is one example in [github](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) , what should I do to find the coordinates? I attached code just to be safe

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function


import collections
import math
import os
import random
import zipfile

import numpy as np
from six.moves import urllib
from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import tensorflow as tf

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
font_location = "c:\\windows\\fonts\\malgun.ttf"
font_name = fm.FontProperties(fname=font_location).get_name()
matplotlib.rc('font', family=font_name)


# Step 1
filename = "text8.zip"

def read_data(filename):
  with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as f:
    data = f.read(f.namelist()[0]).split()
    for i, item in enumerate(data):
        data[i] = item.decode('utf-8')
  return data

words = read_data(filename)
print('Data size', len(words))

# Step 2
vocabulary_size = 10000

def build_dataset(words):
  count = [['UNK', -1]]
  count.extend(collections.Counter(words).most_common(vocabulary_size - 1))
  dictionary = dict()
  for word, _ in count:
    dictionary[word] = len(dictionary)
  data = list()
  unk_count = 0
  for word in words:
    if word in dictionary:
      index = dictionary[word]
    else:
      index = 0  # dictionary['UNK']
      unk_count += 1
    data.append(index)
  count[0][1] = unk_count
  reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
  return data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary

data, count, dictionary, reverse_dictionary = build_dataset(words)
del words  # Hint to reduce memory.
print('Most common words (+UNK)', count[:5])
print('Sample data', data[:10], [reverse_dictionary[i] for i in data[:10]])

data_index = 0

# Step 3
def generate_batch(batch_size, num_skips, skip_window):
  global data_index
  assert batch_size % num_skips == 0
  assert num_skips <= 2 * skip_window
  batch = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size), dtype=np.int32)
  labels = np.ndarray(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.int32)
  span = 2 * skip_window + 1 # [ skip_window target skip_window ]
  buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=span)
  for _ in range(span):
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
  for i in range(batch_size // num_skips):
    target = skip_window  # target label at the center of the buffer
    targets_to_avoid = [ skip_window ]
    for j in range(num_skips):
      while target in targets_to_avoid:
        target = random.randint(0, span - 1)
      targets_to_avoid.append(target)
      batch[i * num_skips + j] = buffer[skip_window]
      labels[i * num_skips + j, 0] = buffer[target]
    buffer.append(data[data_index])
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(data)
  return batch, labels

batch, labels = generate_batch(batch_size=8, num_skips=2, skip_window=1)
for i in range(8):
  print(batch[i], reverse_dictionary[batch[i]],
      '->', labels[i, 0], reverse_dictionary[labels[i, 0]])

# Step 4

batch_size = 128
embedding_size = 128  
skip_window = 1       
num_skips = 2        

valid_size = 16     
valid_window = 100  
valid_examples = np.random.choice(valid_window, valid_size, replace=False)
num_sampled = 64    

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():


  train_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  # Ops and variables pinned to the CPU because of missing GPU implementation
  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_inputs)


    nce_weights = tf.Variable(
        tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                            stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
    nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))


  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.nce_loss(nce_weights, nce_biases, embed, train_labels,
                     num_sampled, vocabulary_size))

  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
      normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  similarity = tf.matmul(
      valid_embeddings, normalized_embeddings, transpose_b=True)

# Step 5
num_steps = 100001

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print("Initialized")

  average_loss = 0
  for step in xrange(num_steps):
    batch_inputs, batch_labels = generate_batch(
        batch_size, num_skips, skip_window)
    feed_dict = {train_inputs : batch_inputs, train_labels : batch_labels}

    _, loss_val = session.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    average_loss += loss_val

    if step % 2000 == 0:
      if step > 0:
        average_loss /= 2000
      print("Average loss at step ", step, ": ", average_loss)
      average_loss = 0

    # Note that this is expensive (~20% slowdown if computed every 500 steps)
    if step % 10000 == 0:
      sim = similarity.eval()
      for i in xrange(valid_size):
        valid_word = reverse_dictionary[valid_examples[i]]
        top_k = 8 
        nearest = (-sim[i, :]).argsort()[1:top_k+1]
        log_str = "Nearest to %s:" % valid_word
        for k in xrange(top_k):
          close_word = reverse_dictionary[nearest[k]]
          log_str = "%s %s," % (log_str, close_word)
        print(log_str)
  final_embeddings = normalized_embeddings.eval()


# Step 6

def plot_with_labels(low_dim_embs, labels, filename='tsne.png'):
  assert low_dim_embs.shape[0] >= len(labels), "More labels than embeddings"
  plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18))  #in inches
  for i, tmlab in enumerate(labels):
    # slabel = tmlab.decode('utf-8')
    x, y = low_dim_embs[i,:]
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.annotate(tmlab,
                 xy=(x, y),
                 xytext=(5, 2),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 ha='right',
                 va='bottom')

  plt.savefig(filename)

try:
  from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  tsne = TSNE(perplexity=30, n_components=2, init='pca', n_iter=5000)
  plot_only = 750
  low_dim_embs = tsne.fit_transform(final_embeddings[:plot_only,:])
  labels = [reverse_dictionary[i] for i in xrange(plot_only)]
  plot_with_labels(low_dim_embs, labels)

except ImportError:
  print("Please install sklearn and matplotlib to visualize embeddings.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your embedding dimension could be arbitrarily large (50-300 or more). But, you want to plot the words on a 2 dimensional space. Since, your embedding size is 128 which is much larger than 2 you need to project these embeddings in a 2d-space. The most well-known method for this problem is [T-SNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html). You can use code from this [Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-visualise-word2vec-word-vectors/answer/Vered-Shwartz?srid=R9Tv). It worked for me. Kindly upvote if this solved your issue!

Comment: But what if we just want to store the original coordinates for further calculation? In which object are they saved?